# Nodejs with Angularjs : angular controller scripts not executed

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, ejs

I am currently working on a Node project using Express and ejs as view engine.

Now, for some purposes, I want to put some Angularjs on the project but I encountered some issues.

None of the scripts I write on the Angularjs controller are executed though they are correctly loaded.

For example, I initiate the angular module like so in a file app.js

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('MainController', MainController);
```

then I load it in a rendered ejs file index.ejs

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div>{{ variable }}</div>
<script src="/public/js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="/public/modules/part.js"></script>
<script scr="/public/modules/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

where /public is a the static directory for serving static files and part.js the file containing the MainController defined as following

```
var MainController = function($scope) {
    $scope.variable = 'text';
    console.log('other text');
}
```

When the page is completely loaded, nothing in the console and the {{ variable }} isn't interpreted.

So what have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add **`ng-controller="MainController"`** as well,

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainController">
    <div>{{ variable }}</div>
</body>
```